# Authorization/Authorization button in azure data factory for data lake store not replace Authorization and session id in JSON

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory, azure-data-lake

Authorization/Authorization button in azure data factory for data lake store not replace Authorization and session id in JSON.

I am using mozilla Firefox or chrome browser

Answer (score 0):

I have also experienced this a couple of times. My advice would be to use Microsoft Edge if you have to do this via the Azure Portal and always have a clean browser session when you do. Or even an 'InPrivate' window just for the authorisation because of the pop ups and the way it actually adds the keys to the JSON.

**OR**

Even better than using the session authorisation, you can now authenticate against Azure Data Lake storage with an Azure AD service principal. This is a far better approach as keys do not expire and you wouldn't need to repeat the process above.

Check out this link for details on how service to service auth works:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-lake-store/data-lake-store-authenticate-using-active-directory

Hope this helps.